# Append my "AppName" with "DefaultDirName" in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to append my `AppName` with  `DefaultDirName`.

like

```
AppName=MyInstaller
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\{#AppName}
```

path look like : `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\MyInstaller`

**code:**

```
[Setup]
UsePreviousAppDir=no
AppName=MyInstaller
AppVersion=1.5                    
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\{#AppName}
DefaultGroupName=MyInstaller
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyInstaller.exe
```

I'm unable to append app name with `DefaultDirName`.

Please someone help me, how to append it?

Comment: And what error or behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @mirtheil I got an error "[ISPP] Undeclared identifier "AppName". "

Comment: That's because you're not defining AppName as an ISPP constant.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [SetupSetting](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting) preprocessor function for expanding `[Setup]` section directive values.

```
AppName=MyInstaller
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\{#SetupSetting("AppName")}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the base installer file as created by the InnoSetup Wizard.  It uses a constant for `AppName` and appends it to `DefaultDirName`. This was built using InnoSetup 5.5.9(u)

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{FCC9E92F-AE28-4067-8E23-596A4AB90705}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```